Очень тяжёлый bundle.js при сборке
Собираю проект на реакт + webpack. В проекте всего две почти пустых страницы, а финальный js файл имеет огромную строку и весит больше мегабайта. В чём может быть причина такого явления?
{
  "name": "webpackdeep",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --env mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --env mode=production",
    "start": "webpack serve --env port=4090"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.5",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0",
    "sass": "^1.76.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  }
}


Ну откуда ж мы знаем. Может вы туда войну и мир запихали…

318 kB(на самом деле меньше) + 4.51 MB(на самом деле меньше) + Dependencies
